# When using functions and ' while True' in python , i get a 'None' in result , which is not supposed to be there. Pls help me with this

Tags: python, function, math

I'm learning python , and decided to write a program which takes a undefined number of inputs and gives the 'sum' and 'max' from math module , where the inputs are first stored in a list (b) and then passed to a function . I'm not sure if there is an another way to do this ( actually used *args and a lot of 'if' conditions before i could get a desired result, and my current code is the closest to it)
I'm fairly new to stackoverflow too , so tips on how i presented my question and how i can improve it will help too~

```
def dc(args):
        print('sum :', sum(args) ,'Max :', max(args))
        return
b=[]
while True:
        a = input('->')
        if a == "":
                break
        b.append(int(a))

 
 
print(dc(b))
```

#so function `dc` returns sum and max. And used `while True` keep giving input untill a blank line - `""` is given before adding them to list `b[]`

what I expected ...

```
->1
->2
->3
->
sum : 6 Max : 3
```

What I got ...

```
->1
->2
->3
->
sum : 6 Max : 3
None
```

And i don't understand where the `None` came from

Comment: Don't print the result of `dc` then.

Comment: since you are not setting a variable to the `dc` function, you do not need `return`

Comment: *printing* and *returning* are quite different. Your function does print values, but returns nothing. Look for `return` in Python docs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly the returning of None has nothing to do with the While loop.

What you have defined is a void function. There are two types of functions, a value(s) returning type of function and a void function.
Void functions do not return anything. And when a function does not return anything, it returns None value, which is like 'nothing' in regular English.

Do not use values like 'a' or 'b' as variable names, use values that are descriptive of what that variable holds.

I also recommend having a data-type check with a try block. Refer the code below and the outputs shown. Here the function is returning two values, the sum(input_list) and max(input_list).

```
def max_and_sum_of_list(input_list):
        print('Sum :', sum(input_list) ,'Max :', max(input_list))
        return sum(input_list), max(input_list)

input_list=[]
while True:
        input_number = input('->')
        if input_number == "":
                break
        try:
         input_list.append(int(input_number))
         
        except ValueError as value_error: 
            print("Incorrect input data-type", str(value_error))

 
sum_of_numbers, max_of_numbers = max_and_sum_of_list(input_list)
```

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I never knew about void functions. I learned py mostly from w3 schools and there they just defined a function and put some examples for it

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code

```py
def dc(args):
        return 'sum :', sum(args) ,'Max :', max(args)
b=[]
while True:
        a = input('->')
        if a == "":
                break
        b.append(int(a))

 
 
print(dc(b))
```

This happened because you have returned a `None` object and things actually go fine with the `print()` function. Here, I have returned the sum of args and max of args instead of printing it as it is  a function

Comment: This will return a tuple in an undesired  output format.